# glibc detected double free or corruption(!prev) using shared library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

Currently I test a shared library vendor provided in linux , 
the following is the simple source :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern int test1();
extern int test2();

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl ;
    return 0 ;
    cout << "Test 1" << endl;
    test1();

    cout << "Test 2" << endl;
    test2();

    return 0;
}
```

I have compile and link like :

g++ -g -Wall -fPIC -D_DEBUG -o test -I./include32 src/xxx.cpp src/yyy.cpp  src/test.cpp 
-L./lib32 -lshare1 -lshared2

I have the following output while run :

```
hello world
***glibc detected *** ./test: double free or corrution (!prev) 0x00000000077ec30 ***
```

What I don't get is , since I only do print "hello world" and then return 0 ,
that mean I don't call any function in libshared1.so  and libshared2.so ,
why error like glibc detected happen ?  does it mean that shared library has 
problem to be loaded to memory ? since the main function never call test1() , test2()
which really call functions in libshared1.so and libshared2.so  !!

And suggestions , comments are most appreciated !!

Edit :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "hello world 3 " << endl ;
    void *handle2;
    handle2 = dlopen ("/usr/local/lib/xxx.so", RTLD_LAZY);   
    if (!handle2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "hello world 1 " << endl ;
    void *handle3;
    handle3 = dlopen ("/usr/local/lib/yyy.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }


    cout << "hello world" << endl ;
}
```

Compile :

```
 g++ -g -Wall -rdynamic -o test src/test.cpp -ldl
```

Output :

```
 hello world 3
 hello world 1
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The Vendor really provide damaged shared library ?!

Comment: Run in debugger and see backtrace. Most likely it is caused by faulty library constructor/destructor.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind. It will tell you about invalid memory accesses even if they don't immediately result in a segfault.